# spinnaker on kubernetes can't create application, just loading

Tags: spinnaker

i installed spinnaker using k8s follow https://github.com/spinnaker/spinnaker/tree/master/experimental/kubernetes/simple, all pods looks good, i can login but i can't create application. it just loading. i have checked the logs on gate, there are some questions:

```
: ---> HTTP GET http://spin-front50.spinnaker:8080/v2/applications
: <--- HTTP 404 http://spin-front50.spinnaker:8080/v2/applications (10ms)
```

front50 health status is UP. it looks like there is no the URL. 
any ideas? thanks.

Answer (score -1):

I also got that problem, and i change to https://www.spinnaker.io/setup/install/environment/, you can have a try, hope helps.

Comment: Please copy here concerned codes, links can be changed or removed